# unique constraint with objects.get_or_create

Tags: django

I've a unique constraint error : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: wikis_article.title

this is my code:

```
def Article_Edit(request, articleid):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk = articleid)
    form = EditForm(instance=article)
    if request.method == "POST":
        article_form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if article_form.is_valid():
            Article.objects.get_or_create(
                title=article_form.cleaned_data["title"],
                content=article_form.cleaned_data["content"],
            )

            messages.success(request, 'article successfully added')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("Article_List"))

    return render(request, 'wikis/article_create.html', {"form": form})
```

with my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=512, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,verbose_name=_("title"))
    content = MarkdownxField(blank=True, verbose_name=_("article contents"))
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name=_("created"),
    )
    modified = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        verbose_name=_("modified"),
        help_text=_("Article properties last modified"),
    )
```

I know that if I delete my unique constraint on tile, I think this will work. But I need to maintain this constraint. I don't understand which get_or_create does not see that I M on editing an existing instance.

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand which `get_or_create` does not see that I M on editing an existing instance.

It does see this, but you instruct it the wrong way. What you basically say is:

> Create a new article with the given title and content and only if *both* the title and the content are the same as one in the database, you should get that record.

If the content is thus different, but the title the same, then it will raise an error.

You can however simply get the article if the exists one with the same title, you do this by moving the `content` to the `defaults=…` parameter in the [**`.get_or_create(…)`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
Article.objects.get_or_create(
    title=article_form.cleaned_data['title'],
    defaults={'content': article_form.cleaned_data['content']}
)
```

this will however *not* update the record. Indeed, if an `Article` with the same title already exists, we leave the `Article` the way it is. We can use [**`.update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) to update the object in caset the article already exists:

```
Article.objects.update_or_create(
    title=article_form.cleaned_data['title'],
    defaults={'content': article_form.cleaned_data['content']}
)
```

But *both* do not look what you probably want to do. Imagine that the user wants to *rename* an article, then with the given logic, it will create a *new* article, and thus now there are *two* articles. Furthermore if that person changes the name, and it *happens* to be that there is already an article with the given name, then they will (accidently) override the content of that article.

What you probably want to do is *update* the `article`, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def Article_Edit(request, articleid):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=articleid)
    form = EditForm(instance=article)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_form = CreateForm(request.POST, instance=article)
        if article_form.is_valid():
            article_form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'article successfully added')
            return redirect('Article_List')

    return render(request, 'wikis/article_create.html', {'form': form})
```

If the `CreateForm` is a `ModelForm`, it will normally check the uniqness constraint.